# using packages in vhdl

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

There are a few modules and a package in VHDL. How will we use the package in the modules. we have already use.work.Package_name.all;
but it did not work. 
And where will we store the package and the modules? Please specify an example path.
How to compile the package?

Comment: You should at least explain everything you did. Question is very vague.

Comment: The syntax is `use work.Package_name.all;`. Where you store them does not matter, you have to tell your tool where it is stored. What tool are you using?

Comment: @Juergen so, basically what I said in my answer...

Answer (score -1):

I think you should start reading a book on VHDL, or follow an on-line tutorial. Or ask your teacher/tutor.

Google also helps: [vhdl packages](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~jmoorkan/vhdlref/vhdl.html)

```
use work.Package_name.all;
```